# Including a large library in multiple .h files

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm working with the SFML library for C++.  It contains a lot of snazzy game engine features, one of these being the ability to read and store "textures" as a data type.

I'm creating a Game Object hierarchy of enemies, obstacles, and friendlies and such, AKA all of the entities that I will need to draw and interact with on the screen.  Most of these will need to have a texture from SFML's Graphics library.  If I import < SFML/Graphics.hpp >, which I assume is a fairly large library (**am I even calling this by the right word?**), then what am I actually doing to my file?  Will the project tack on the entire < SFML/Graphics.hpp > to my game engine file every time I instantiate a new game object whose .h file includes this library?

**TL;DR, what does importing a library in C++ really do, and is there a danger of importing it unnecessarily many times?  How can I recognize/avoid this danger?**

Comment: The header files you include are *not* the actual libraries. The actual libraries is what you link with.

Comment: And to answer your question, most library headers should have [*include guards*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which prevent them from being included multiple times in the same [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).